# Cannot type "#" in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a hungarian keyboard, on which I have to press "AltGr + X" or "Ctrl + Alt + X" to write a "#".
But windows has it's shortcut for the same button combination to make a screen save...
I couldn't find a way to change it in the settings, maybe I didn't search the right place.

Comment: If Windows is taking a screenshot then your keyboard layout does not match your keyboard.  By default Windows does not have a conflicts like that.

Comment: Windows doesn't have any global Ctrl+Alt shortcuts apart from Ctrl+Alt+Del so that's from some 3rd party applications. Global shortcuts must be formed from the Windows key. To take screenshot you use Alt+PrnScr, PrnScr, Win+PrnScr or Win+Shift+S

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on whether you want to remove the shortcut mapping for `Ctrl+Alt+X`, or whether you just need an alternative method for entering '#'?

You can type # by holding down `Alt` then pressing `0 0 3 5` in sequence.

I don't think the mapping for `Ctrl+Alt+X` is standard, but if you know what it opens you can search for a shortcut for that and check the 'Shortcut Key' setting in its Properties to perhaps amend or delete the mapping.

Comment: Both methods would be good, I am writing python script and want to write comments in it...